# Uncountable nouns and pronouns

Tags: idioms, pronouns, nouns

I'd like ask you about uncountable nouns and their pronouns.
①When we refer to two uncountable nouns as pronouns, can we use "them"?
②If so, why is "it" used in this second sentence? What does "it" refer to?

> It's true that we'll always need news and information. But the way it is delivered will surely keep changing.

Comment: It's a mistake. The second sentence should be "But the way they are delivered will surely keep changing."

Comment: I disagree. I have no problem with treating "news and information" as a "singular, collective" noun here. No different to, say, *Fish and chips **is** expensive these days.*

Comment: [*But **news and information is** clearly no longer the exclusive domain of professionals.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22but+news+and+information+is%22)

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes, you can use "them".
2. Because "news and information" can be referred to either as two different things, or as one collective category.

Comment: Thank you for answering my questions. I'd like to ask you further question. In no.2, news and information can be reffered to as one collective category. What kind of words that could be categorized as one? Do you have any examples?

Comment: @02l4 It's not so much the kind of words, as it is whether you are talking about them as one thing, or as separate things. "News and information" is often referred to as a category. Other examples: "Fish and chips makes a tasty lunch." "The stars and stripes is a nice flag," but "The stars and stripes represent different things." One test you can try, is if the sentence could be broken into sentences about each thing, would the meaning change, or not. If it would, then it's probably a collective singular group being referred to. If not, then they're being talked about as plural things.

Comment: Thank you very much.